# IOS xcode 6 Storyboard Auto Layouts

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout

I need to create a simple login screen in my iPhone app and finding it difficult to adjust my `TextField` to take full width with the container considering '`Trailing space to Container`'...

I have placed `TextFields` and `Labels` within a scroll view and have specified the following constraints

**Username Label**

```
- "Leading Space to Container"
- "Top Space to Container"
- "Horizontal Spacing to the 'Username' TextField"
```

**Username TextField**

```
- "Horizontal spacing to 'Username' Label"
- "Top Spacing to Container"
- "Trailing Space to Contaner"
```

**My UI is as follows**:

[image]

Getting the following warning regarding the width but if i set it to 471 as it suggest it goes outside the scroll view and not accessible

[image]

If ignore the warning and run in simulator the textFiled does not take fill width within container keeping the '`Trailing Space to Contaner`'...

**All I get is this when I run:**

[image]

What should I do to get the `TextField` the full length with in container (keeping the `Trailing Space to Container`)

Comment: Set trailing space of upper textField to the container and make lower textfield right alignment to the upper textfield

Comment: Did you apply all the constraints top,leading,trailing,bottom constraint to the scrollview I think your scrollview is expanding give a background color to your scrollview and check it where is the issue

Comment: HI Muhammad, yes I have added those constraints to the container (scroll view)... Also haven't add any constraints to the lower textfield and it's ok for that behaviour of it... Trying to sort out upper TextField (Username TextField) issue. It does not take full width within container ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made this view Don"t keep all your stuff directly in to the scrollview place a new view into the scrollview and apply a new constraint equal width with the scrollview will solve all your problems.I can give you the code too if you will not be able to apply them.

best of Luck
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its a good practice to take UIView on UIScrollview. Now to set proper width of text field that changes with screen size, you need to set Top,horizontal space with label,Trailing space. Also you can set its Aspect ratio, if there is any misplaced views warning.